# How can I display an arraylist in a JList?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlist

I want to display the all the details of elements in arraylist bikes in a Jlist. I've been trying to figure out how to do this for a while but I just can't crack it. The Jlist is part of a panel called pnlBikesTab.

**ArrayList and JList**

```
 ArrayList<Bike> bikes = new ArrayList<Bike>();
 JList<String> lstBikes ;
```

**Populating Arraylist**

```
 public void Intial(){
//Add 12 bikes  
 Bike b1 = new Bike(1, "Mountain", 12, "Not available") ;       
    Bike b2 = new Bike(2, "Road", 10, "Available") ;         
    Bike b3 = new Bike(3, "City", 8, "Available") ; 
    Bike b4 = new Bike(4, "Mountain", 12, "Available") ;   
    Bike b5 = new Bike(5, "Road", 10, "Available") ;    
    Bike b6 = new Bike(6, "City", 8, "Available") ;        
    Bike b7 = new Bike(7, "Mountain", 12, "Available") ;
    Bike b8 = new Bike(8,"Road", 10, "Available") ;
    EBike b9 = new EBike(9, "eBike", 18, "Not available", "Full Power") ;
    EBike b10 = new EBike(10, "eBike", 18, "Available", "Full Power");
    EBike b11 = new EBike(11, "eBike", 14, "Available", "Power Assist") ;
    EBike b12 = new EBike(12, "eBike", 14, "Available", "Power Assist") ;
    bikes.add(b1) ;
    bikes.add(b2) ;
    bikes.add(b3) ;
    bikes.add(b4) ;
    bikes.add(b5) ;
    bikes.add(b6) ;
    bikes.add(b7) ;
    bikes.add(b8) ;
    bikes.add(b9) ;
    bikes.add(b10) ;
    bikes.add(b11) ;
    bikes.add(b12) ;
}
```

**Main**

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
        BikeNowGUI fr = new BikeNowGUI();
        fr.Intial();
        fr.setTitle("Bikes") ; 
        fr.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //Center frame
        fr.setSize(300, 500);
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }
```

**GUI**

```
public BikeNowGUI(){
        tabs = new JTabbedPane() ; 
        //BikesTab Panel  
        pnlBikesTab = new JPanel() ;
        lblBikes = new JLabel("Bikes") ; 
        pnlBikesTab.add(lblBikes) ;
        lblImages = new JLabel(icons[0]) ;
        pnlBikesTab.add(lblImages) ;
        //Jlist
        ArrayList<Bike> bikes = new ArrayList<Bike>();
        Bike[] items = new Bike[bikes.size()];
        bikes.toArray(items);
        lstBikes = new JList(items);
        pnlBikesTab.add(lstBikes) ;
        tabs.add("Bikes", pnlBikesTab) ;

        //CustomersTab Panel
        pnlCustomersTab = new JPanel();
        tabs.add("Customers", pnlCustomersTab) ;

        //RentsTab Panel
        pnlRentsTab = new JPanel(); 
        tabs.add("Rents", pnlRentsTab) ;

        add(tabs);
    }
```

Comment: You need to store the result of the `toArray` call, `list.add(bikes.toArray())`.

Comment: Where do I put this code? Where do I get list from?

Comment: `list` is your `JList`. `lstBikes = new JList(bikes.toArray ()) `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@daniu is right. You can use this

`lstBikes = new JList(bikes.toArray());`

Another thing is that bikes will always return size 0 in `BikeNowGUI` because you are calling `BikeNowGUI` first before `Initial` method. I would suggest you move all the code to Initial method.

Comment: @LachlanWilliamson did you move all the code to `BikeNowGUI` ?

Comment: Yes. Now the elements arraylist appear in the listbox.